# Updating duplicate values;

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains unique indexes;lets say

```
A B
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

And i want to update the B column,since sql updates them one by one if it tries to update the first column to 2 for ex i get::

```
A B
1 2
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

And as a result i would get two duplicate values at the 1st and 2nd row and of course an error message.

And i should update the table like that:

```
A B
1 2
1 1
1 3
1 4
```

So whats the course of action i should follow in case of this scenario?

Regards.

Maybe i should update the question abit:
What if i wanted to change the b column completely; such as:

```
A B
1 4
1 2
1 3
1 1
```

Comment: Remove the Unique Index, do your update, and restore the Unique Index?

Comment: How are you trying to do the update? The statement that "sql updates them one by one" doesn't make much sense, unless you're running through a cursor or some other looping mechanism.

Comment: Actually i'm using a "for loop" to update,and i should not remove the index too..

Comment: Using a for loop to update usually is bad practice. If you can find any way around it (like Andreys answer below), that is very much preferable

Comment: Why do you have a unique index in a field that SHOULD have duplicate values at a given time?

Comment: Well to simply put it:i have a column that has a sorting order, 1-2-3-4 for exaple and i want to change this order from a form.So as a result,i should update this with the data taken from a gridview.So i get the data row by row with a for loop,and update it,since the value it tries to update is already in the index,i just fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do the swap in a single statement:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET B = (CASE B WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)
WHERE A = 1 AND B IN (1, 2)
```

**--- EDIT ---**

To update several rows at once, you can do a JOIN-update from the temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #ROWS_TO_UPDATE (
    A int,
    B int,
    NEW_B int,
    PRIMARY KEY (A, B)
);

INSERT INTO #ROWS_TO_UPDATE (A, B, NEW_B) VALUES (1, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO #ROWS_TO_UPDATE (A, B, NEW_B) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO #ROWS_TO_UPDATE (A, B, NEW_B) VALUES (1, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO #ROWS_TO_UPDATE (A, B, NEW_B) VALUES (1, 4, 1);

UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET B = NEW_B
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE JOIN #ROWS_TO_UPDATE
        ON YOUR_TABLE.A = #ROWS_TO_UPDATE.A AND YOUR_TABLE.B = #ROWS_TO_UPDATE.B;

DROP TABLE #ROWS_TO_UPDATE;
```

The above code transforms the following data...

```
A B
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

...to this:

```
A B
1 4
1 2
1 3
1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
UPDATE tbl
SET B = 3 - B
WHERE A = 1 AND B IN (1, 2)
```

Or, generaly, you can use something like that:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET B = CASE B 
        WHEN 1 THEN 2 
        WHEN 2 THEN 1 
    END
WHERE A = 1 AND B IN (1, 2)
```

Another way:
add column C
through your loop fill C column with new values
update field B from C:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET B = C
```

Comment: Could this be implemented to an unlimited rows?What if i had x number of rows for example?

Comment: Yes, if you can write all conditions in the manner like in second example. Or, see the third one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you have a primary key composed of two columns, and you want to swap the two first rows' PK.

If you don't have foreing keys which refers to this primary key, simply change one of the keys to a temporary unused value:

```
A B
1 10000
1 2
```

then change the second row:

```
A B
1 10000
1 1
```

Finally, change the first one:

```
A B
1 2
1 1
```

If you have objects depending on this primary key, you would have to make a copy of the other columns (for example the other columns of 1 1) to a "temporary row", copy the data of the second (1 2) to the first (1 1) and finally copy the "temporary row" to the second (1 2)

This all dependes on how and what you're exactly trying to do. Is it a stored procedure, is it a query... You should show more context.

You could apply this technique to an unlimited number of rows. You can also create a temporary table with key equivalences, and update your table from tha temporary table. So, it will be done in an atomic operation, and it won't violate the PK.

```
create table T
(A int, B int, C char(5),
primary key (A,B))

insert into T values(1,1,'first')
insert into T values(1,2,'secon')
insert into T values(1,3,'third')

create table #KeyChanges
(A int, B int, newA int, newB int)

insert into #KeyChanges values(1,1,1,3)
insert into #KeyChanges values(1,2,1,1)
insert into #KeyChanges values(1,3,1,2)

update T set T.A = KC.newA, T.B = KC.newB
from T
left join #KeyChanges as KC on T.A = KC.A and T.B = KC.B
```